# Confusion between parsing xml and json file

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot, jackson-databind

i am using jackson framwork to convert xml file and csv file to java objects:
i put thoses dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

the parsing of xml is ok, but i want to parse je json file i have this error :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'

codes for xml and json :

```
final XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
        Records records = mapper.readValue(new 
File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(xmlFileName).getFile()), Records.class);

    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
        Object o = mapper.readValue(new 
        File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("reports.json").getFile()),
        Request[].class);
```

have any idea?

Comment: can you paste your JSON file? I assume some issue with it.

Comment: the problem is here : ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
        Object o = mapper.readValue(new .. i use mapper instead of mapper2